# Write an html text inside a div of the next page after window.location redirect using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Is there a way to call a (jquery action/write an html text) to a div of a new page after calling the window.location command?

Im trying to make an ajax form submit where the user will be redirected to a new page upon submit,

and in that new page a hidden div will appear with text inside of it

currently this is my code

**script.js**

```
$.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:'POST',
            data:datastr,
            success:function(result){
            if(result=="duplicate"){
                $("#status").attr('class', 'span12 alert alert-error');
                $("#status").show();
                $("#status").html("<h4><center>Duplicate Username</center></h4>");

                $("#dept_name").closest(".control-group").attr('class', 'control-group');
                $("#username").closest(".control-group").attr('class', 'control-group error');
                $("#password").closest(".control-group").attr('class', 'control-group');

                $("#username").focus();
                }
            else{
                $("#dept_name").closest(".control-group").attr('class', 'control-group');
                $("#username").closest(".control-group").attr('class', 'control-group');
                $("#password").closest(".control-group").attr('class', 'control-group');
                window.location = base + 'admin/departments/edit_dept/' + result;
                }
            }

        });
```

i want to make this block of code below work on the page where window.location is going

```
                $("#status").attr('class', 'span12 alert alert-error');
                $("#status").show();
                $("#status").html("<h4><center>Successfully added Department</center></h4>");
```

is it possible?

thanks

Comment: Can you not have static text on the second page? i.e. a page with an error message and another page with success message. You seem to be redirecting to a page depending on the ajax result anyway.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525584/what-happens-to-code-after-a-javascript-redirect-setting-window-location-href

Comment: i want to make my files as few as possible so i do it with ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CI session flash data.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Before triggering `window.location`, set the message in `flashdata`. On the landing/redirected-to page, check to see if `flashdata` has a value (success/failure). If so, display (or trigger a js method to show) the message.

Comment: this seems to be the easiest way

Answer (score 1):

You could add a parameter with your window.location, like:

```
window.location = base + 'admin/departments/edit_dept/' + result + '?showMessage=12'
```

Then on the next page, have a jquery script that looks for that parameter and shows the message. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery).

Or you can do it in on the server. But with jquery it works with static html too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a patchup, May require some tuning though.

```
window.location = base + 'admin/departments/edit_dept/' + result+'/err';  //changed to catchup with the view part
```

In the Controller:

```
 <?php
    if($this->uri->segment(4) == "err"){
        $data['err']    = true;                 #will reflect that we need to show the js in the view
        $this->load->view('view', $data);
    }
?>
```

In the view part:

```
<?php if(isset($err)){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#status").attr('class', 'span12 alert alert-error');
$("#status").show();
$("#status").html("<h4><center>Successfully added Department</center></h4>");
</script>
<?php } ?>
```