# Executing a click function after redirecting

Tags: javascript, html

index.php (Home page):

```
<a class="whitelink" href="about.php" onclick="redirectcontact()">Contact Us</a>
<a class="whitelink" href="about.php" onclick="redirectfaq()">FAQ</a>
```

About.php (About Us Page) : Basically for this, my function redirectfaq() does not work but my redirectcontact() function works so how do I make them both work as in redirecting and executing click function after clicking the links on home page

```
 function redirectcontact()
        {
             
          window.localStorage.setItem('click',true);
        }
function redirectfaq()
        {
             
          window.localStorage.setItem('click2',true);
        }
        
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
           
              
             if(window.localStorage.getItem('click')) {
                    window.localStorage.removeItem('click');
                    document.getElementById("clickcontact").click();
              }
 if(window.localStorage.getItem('click2')) {
                    window.localStorage.removeItem('click2');
                    document.getElementById("clickfaq").click();
              }
        });
```

Comment: 1) You need to store before changing location 2) localStorage only stores strings.

Comment: You shouldn't put code after `window.location = "..."`, try setting the localstorage item first.

Comment: see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525584/what-happens-to-code-after-a-javascript-redirect-setting-window-location-href)

Comment: You are breaking default anchor behavior by redirecting via JavaScript instead of the `href` attribute. For users who often use their middle mouse button to open pages in new tabs, that is really frustrating.

Comment: ok I have changed it to use href and tried the code but whenever i click away from the about page, it just redirects me back to the about page indefinitely